# Example of a non-strongly $A^1$ invariant sheaf of groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

A Nisnevich sheaf of groups is called strongly $A^1$-invariant if its classifying space $BG$ is $A^1$-invariant. I would like an example that is $A^1$ invariant but not strongly $A^1$-invariant for an arbitrary base scheme. For base scheme a field, the sheafification of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G }_m]/\mathbb{Z}[*]$ is an example. Can someone give me a more general example which is not over a field please?